# An identity related to the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}p(5n+4)x^n$ in Ramanujan's lost notebook

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-partitions, q-series

While browsing through Ramanujan's [original manuscript titled "The Lost Notebook"](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/04/04.pdf) (the link is a PDF file with 379 scanned pages, so instead of a click it is preferable to download) I found this identity (numbered (4.5))  on page 139 $$x\cdot\frac{\left\{(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{15})\dots\right\} ^5} {(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\dots} =\frac{x} {(1-x)^2}-\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}-\frac{x^3}{(1-x^3)^2}+\frac{x^4}{(1-x^4)^2}+\frac{x^6}{(1-x^6)^2}-\frac{x^7}{(1-x^7)^2}-\dots\tag{1}$$ which can be more compactly written as $$x\prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{(1-x^{5n})^5}{1-x^n}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{n}{5}\right)\frac{x^n}{(1-x^n)^2}$$ Next Ramanujan says "it follows from $(1)$ that $$\{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\dots \} ^5\{p(4)x+p(9)x^2+p(14)x^3+\dots\}=5\left\{\frac{x} {(1-x)^2}-\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}-\frac{x^3}{(1-x^3)^2}+\frac{x^4}{(1-x^4)^2}+\frac{x^6}{(1-x^6)^2}-\dots\right\}\tag{2}$$ and hence that  $$p(4)+p(9)x+p(14)x^2+p(19)x^3+\dots=5\cdot\frac{\{(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{15})\dots\}^5 } {\{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\dots\}^6}\tag{3} $$ Here $p(n) $ denotes the number of unrestricted partitions of a positive integer $n $ and $\left(\dfrac{a}{p} \right) $ denotes the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

The identity $(3)$ mentioned above is famous and is used to derive many partition congruences with $$p(5n+4)\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$ as an immediate consequence. A complete proof of $(3)$ based on different ideas is available in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1955431/72031).

It took me sometime to figure out as to how $(2)$ follows from $(1)$. The technique Ramanujan uses here is to expand both sides in powers of $x$ and then pick only the terms with $x^{5n}$ and replace $x^5$ by $x$. In this process we also make use of the fact that $$1+\sum_{n\geq 1}p(n)x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\dots}\tag{4}$$

What is really mysterious is the origin of the identity $(1)$ and I am trying to find a proof. I did check the nearby pages of the Lost Notebook and did not find any proofs or hint. However on the same page 139 of the notebook there is another identity (numbered (4.6)) $$\frac{\left\{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\dots\right\} ^5} {(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{15})\dots} =1-5\left(\frac{x} {1-x}-\frac{2x^2}{1-x^2}-\frac{3x^3}{1-x^3}+\frac{4x^4}{1-x^4}+\frac{6x^6}{1-x^6}-\frac{7x^7}{1-x^7}-\dots\right) \tag{5}$$ The identities $(1),(5)$ appear intimately tied to each other and seem to come out of nowhere.

Any proofs or references regarding proofs of the identities $(1),(5)$ are desired.

Comment: A Proof has been given here :
[New Proofs of Ramanujan′s Partition Identities for Moduli 5 and 7 - H. H. Chan](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X85710839)
Theorem 2.3 and (2.14)

Comment: @BlackEmperor: thanks a lot for the reference. The proof appears quite long and may not really fit an answer here. The same paper also contains a short proof (by F. Garvan) of a similar identity for modulo 7 and perhaps we can use something similar for the identity in question here.